# Avoid validation on hidden fields - Webmatrix

Tags: razor, html-helper, webmatrix

I got a form with some hidden fields that are only displayed if an option is selected.

I got this line to validate

```
Validation.RequireFields("atividade", "contaCliente", "contaServico", "nomeCliente", "dataAgendamento");
```

The first four fields are always visible, however the field `dataAgendamento` only appears if an option is selected like I said above.

That said when I try to to submit the form, I get an error that `dataAgendamento` is required. Is there some way to avoid validation on hidden fields?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're having the Option visible only when the Condition is true. You can check or execute the validation only when the condition is true.

Do this,

```
Validation.RequireFields("atividade", "contaCliente", 
"contaServico", "nomeCliente");
// Remove the last validator, and add it using a condition

if(valueFromSelect == "somecondition") {
   Validation.RequireField("dataAgendamento", "Required visible field!");
}
```

This would make the field required only if the condition (value in the select clause is true) otherwise it won't add the Validation to the field.

Comment: Thanks mate. I used that on other page that i needed to extract reports if they have a certain condition. I didn't think on that solution for this problem, because i thought that validation requires something else. Noob here :|